# Changing the Form Title dynamically on button Click in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, rxjs, react-router

I want to change the title of my Form dynamically based on the value passed on button Click.
For ex:
My Form Title is `Book Health Care Services`.
And I want to change the Title of my Form to `Book Doctor Consult Services` whenever I navigate to the form on button click I want to change the title of the form.

The button is located in component A & the form Title is located in component B.

How can I make this happen. Can somebody help me out.

Comment: Can you share your two components? Easy answer would be that you pass a prop for the title, so that when the button changes it, the change is reflected in the upper component. But I don't know how you've written or structured it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this structure:

```
import { useState } from "react";

// you need a mother component for passing variables from component A to B
export default function MotherOfAAndB(props) {
    // changing variables need to be stored in state variables, this is a
    // React pattern
    const [formTitle, setFormTitle] = useState("");

    // by using this function in the mother component and passing it with 
    // props to the component A, you can pass formTitle from component A to 
    // mother component, this is a React pattern, and then you can pass it 
    // to component B as props
    function onChangeFormTitle(formTitle) {
        // changing state varibale "formTitle" for passing it through props 
        // to component B
        setFormTitle(formTitle)
    }

    return <>
        <A
            // passing function "onChangeFormTitle" through props to
            // component A, provides ability to pass vairables from inside
            // of component A to mother component for any other uses
            onChangeFormTitle={onChangeFormTitle}
        />
        <B
            // passing "formTitle" variable to component B, the main pupose 
            // of previous efforts
            formTitle={formTitle}
        />
    </>
}

// component A could be either in separate file (using import at the top of 
// this file) or in current file (no need to import)
function A(props) {
    // we need state variables for changing values, this is a React pattern
    const [formTitleInComponentA, setFormTitleInComponentA] = useState("");

    // handle changing of input value
    function onChange(e) {
        // changing state variable "formTitleInComponentA"
        setFormTitleInComponentA(e.target.value)
    }
    return <>
        <input
            type="text"
            onChange={onChange}
            // setting value={formTitleInComponentA} is needed otherwise you 
            // can't set the value of input variables in state variables for 
            // other usages, this is a React pattern
            value={formTitleInComponentA}
        />
        <button
            // passing "formTitleInComponentA" to "props.onChangeFormTitle", 
            // cause to change state variable "formTitle" in mother 
            // component
            onClick={() => props.onChangeFormTitle(formTitleInComponentA)}
        />
    </>
}

// component A could be either in separate file (using import at the top of 
// this file) or in current file (no need to import)
function B(props) {
    // any usage of variable "formTitle"
    return <>{props.formTitle}</>
}
```

**UPDATE**
If you place `props.onChangeFormTitle(formTitleInComponentA)` in `onChange(e)` in component `A`, provide realtime changing of formTitle in component `B`

Comment: Hey ProactiveThinker, thanks for your reply. But its really confusing for me especially the "title". Can you please make it much easier to understand by putting some example in it.

Comment: Hi @ParikshitBharadwaj, I add some comments in the answer, hope help. Can you explain more about your confusing?