# state and props of different file components

Tags: reactjs, state, react-component

I apologize in advance if the answer to your question is obvious but I'm new to React and can't find the answer on your website.
I have two components in different files in the same folder. I want to get the state of component1 in component2 but it gives me an error. How can I get the state or props of components that are in different files?.
How can I know which element generates an event, for example if I have 7 buttons and I want to know which of them generates an event, also from components of different files.
The components are in the same folder:
carpeta1¬
componente1.js
componente2.js

The code is the following:

```
//componente1.js
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'
import cn1 from '../../public/lared.png'

class Componente1 extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.cambiarSenal = this.cambiarSenal.bind(this);
     this.state = {senal: ""};
   }

   cambiarSenal(event){
     let btn = event.target;        
     this.setState({
        senal: 'https://www.lared.cl/senal-online'
     });
   }

   render(){
     return( 
        <div className="root">
            <div className={styles.ctElm}>
                <div className={styles.ctImg} id="ctImg"><Image src= {cn1} alt='cn1' className={styles.img}/></div>
                   <p className={styles.ctTt} onClick={this.cambiarSenal}><Link href='/carpeta1/senalLive'><a className={styles.enl}>La Red</a></Link></p>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    });
}
export default Componente1;

//componente2.js
import React from 'react'    

class SenalLive extends React.Component{
   render(){
     return(
        
        <div className={styles.root}> 
           <div className={styles.cnl}>
               <iframe className={styles.frm} src={state.senal}></iframe>
           </div>
        </div>
   });
}
export return SenalLive;
```

It is summarized. In the iframe I would call the state of the component1.
I am using state because I am going to use several

, each one will have the event of changing the link for the use of component2 which will change the url of the iframe according to the change of state

Comment: Can you show us the code and what you have tried

Comment: This link may help:
[Using states of a component in another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70710472/changing-the-form-title-dynamically-on-button-click-in-react-js/70710760#70710760)